# how to fetch and remove a script on the body before it loaded

Tags: javascript, html, brightcove

I have a Script in the Body and i want that my script in the Head will remove the script on the body before it loaded,
can i do that?(with no jquery)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--this is my script the will invoke function to remove the body script-->
    <script src="myScript.js" publisherid="f30ae105891798ee83e5bc2ada72c4a1" ></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/top.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
    <body>
        <!--i want to remove this script before he loaded-->
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
        <object id="myExperience3970037216001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
            <param name="width" value="480" />
            <param name="height" value="270" />
            <param name="playerID" value="3962670776001" />
            <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAADmfA5E4E~,VCox43IgXh94Y0wqtES6bXCLsUxMtUOK" />
            <param name="isVid" value="true" />
            <param name="isUI" value="true" />
            <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
            <param name="@videoPlayer" value="3970037216001" />

        </object>
        <script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think so - `<script>` tags are evaluated as the HTML parser reads them (and block further HTML parsing whilst they are executing). Therefore for a `<script>` element to exist in the DOM it must already have been evaluated.

Comment: I don't think you can remove it, the fastest solution I'm thinking about is actually overwriting the createExperiences method, by making it void.

Comment: Yea, that ain't possible. If it were, it would be too damn easy to break scripts.

Comment: or just try head.removeChild(script);

Comment: @ZeRubeus: You can't remove a child until it's been parsed into the DOM. Which means it's already executed.

Comment: Thinking a little bit more, I think you must parse a <script> tag after the object, and do something like this: `<script>brightcove.prototype.createExperiences = function() { return false; };</script>`. <-- This should overwrite the createExperiences function which is exectuted right after it.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a variable from my script.js, let's call it toExecute. Then define it to true or false if you want the body script to execute or not, like so:

var toExecute = true;  // or false..

Then change

brightcove.createExperiences();

to

if (toExecute) brightcove.createExperiences();

Comment: I think the point is that the script in the body cannot be changed. If it could, you could just remove it!

Comment: exactly, i cant change the script in the body.